# Every time I try update (using sudo apt update) my Ubuntu I get this problem:

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04

Every time I try update my Ubuntu using `sudo apt update`, I get this problem:

```
Reading package lists... Done       
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 22.04 L22.04 LTS TS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220419) jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I fix it?
I use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

In your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, there are some mirrors set to install from your CD installation media.

You need to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove every line starting with `cdrom://`.

Comment: Or just comment them out by adding `#` before those lines instead of removing